# How to draw the `normalizedPoints` of `VNFaceLandmarkRegion2D` on my UIView?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

I am trying to draw a circle to represent the result of leftPupil detected by `VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest`.

By the naming convention of `normalizedPoints`, I guess it is normalized by some rules. So, how can I scale and translate the point to my `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` or other views?

From some Vision tutorials, I have seen transformation like below:

```
let faceLandmarkPoints = convertedPoints.map { (point: (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)) -> (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) in
                    let pointX = point.x * boundingBox.width + boundingBox.origin.x
                    let pointY = point.y * boundingBox.height + boundingBox.origin.y

                    return (x: pointX, y: pointY)
                }
```

However, it doesn't really work for me. My complete code is given below.

Transformation:

```
// Rescale the points from vision coordinates
func convertPointsForFace(landmark: VNFaceLandmarkRegion2D?, _ boundingBox: CGRect)
    -> [(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)]?{
        if let points = landmark?.normalizedPoints{
            let convertedPoints = self.convertToCGFloat(points: points)

            let faceLandmarkPoints = convertedPoints.map { (point: (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)) -> (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) in
                let pointX = point.x * boundingBox.width + boundingBox.origin.x
                let pointY = point.y * boundingBox.height + boundingBox.origin.y

                return (x: pointX, y: pointY)
            }
            return faceLandmarkPoints
        }
        return nil
}
```

Draw the point:

```
// Draw a point on preview layer
func drawPoint(point: (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)){
    // We use a CAShaperLayer to draw the circle
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: point.x,y: point.y),
                                  radius: CGFloat(20),
                                  startAngle: CGFloat(0),
                                  endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2),
                                  clockwise: true)
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
    self.previewLayer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

`VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest` completion handler:

```
func landmarkDetectCcompletionHandler(request: VNRequest, _ error: Error?){
    if error != nil {
        print("Errors in the landmark detection: \(error.debugDescription)")
    }
    guard let observations = request.results as? [VNFaceObservation] else {
        fatalError("Failed to convert result to VNFaceObservation type")
    }
    for face in observations {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            [weak self] in
            let faceBox = face.boundingBox
            let leftEye = face.landmarks?.leftPupil
            let leftEyePoints = self?.convertPointsForFace(landmark: leftEye,
                                                           faceBox)
            print(leftEyePoints?.first!.x, leftEyePoints?.first!.y)
            self?.drawPoint(point: (leftEyePoints?.first)!)
        }
    }
}
```

The filled circle always shows up on the top left of my `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideopreviewlayer)'s

- [layerPointConverted(fromCaptureDevicePoint:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideopreviewlayer/1623502-layerpointconverted) or
- [layerRectConverted(fromMetadataOutputRect:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideopreviewlayer/1623498-layerrectconverted) ?